# cannot remove $base_url address from a link

Tags: 7, javascript

There is a Ads block in my website in which some websites logo and their address are placed in there. I created a content type for it , called `Ads` (and also a view `Ads__view`). it has two fields : 1.link 2.logo . I created a slide show using `slideShow` module and it slides the logos. I want my website to redirect to these websites when user clicks on any of them, so I created a page called `views-view-fields--Ads__view.tpl.php` and this is the code of it :

```
<?php 
$address = strip_tags($fields['field_Ads_link']->content);
?>
<a href="<?php print $address ?>"><?php print $fields['field_Ads_photo']->content; ?></a>
```

the problem is `$base_url` of my website is attached at the beginning of the  `($fields['field_Ads_link']->content` for example `www.google.com` will be `www.mywebsite.com/www.google.com` . how can I remove this attachment ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to prefix `http://` with your link. If you will not add prefix `http://` with your link, Drupal will treat this as internal url of Drupal site.

So, you should add url `http://www.google.com` in your content.

Or you can use [Link](https://drupal.org/project/link) module to create a `link` field.

> With `link` module links can be added easily to any content types and
>   profiles and include advanced validating and different ways of storing
>   internal or external links and URLs. It also supports additional link
>   text title, site wide tokens for titles and title attributes, target
>   attributes, css class attribution, static repeating values, input
>   conversion, and many more.

Comment: Exactly...a string can't be a URL until it has a _protocol_

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, I tested your solution (with protocol) but it did not work, the protocol and address were attached to the address.

Comment: @Mohammad, then I would suggest you to use `link` module to create link field.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola I already have used this module. this module only accepts text as link not a picture

Comment: @JayendraKainthola the only way that works is adding this code `$address = str_replace($base_url,'',$address);`, I will search how to use `link` module for pictures

Comment: @Mohammad, Link module will allow you to add a link field and you can link that field to picture or text.

Comment: @Mohammad, are you using views for slideshow?

Comment: @JayendraKainthola yes I am

Comment: @Mohammad, then you can use `replacement pattern` in your views to add picture as link.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola thanks for your useful solutions

Comment: @Mohammad, welcome.